# Iterating over dictionaries using loops

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, finance, stock

Goodmorning! I am a beginner in python and I'm struggling with dictionaries. I have these codes and I need to compute the overall pnl of the portfolio.
portfolio

```
portfolio = {
  "AAPL": {
    "volume": 10,
    "strike": 154.12
  },
  "GOOG": {
    "volume": 2,
    "strike": 812.56
  },
  "TSLA": {
    "volume": 12,
    "strike": 342.12
  },
  "FB": {
    "volume": 18,
    "strike": 209.0
  }
}

market = {
  "AAPL":  198.84,
  "GOOG": 1217.93,
  "TSLA":  267.66,
  "FB":    179.06
```

I tried to write the code which It works but it doesn't show me only one value with the total but 4 different value with the total of each asset:

```
for key in market:
    print(key, (portfolio[key]['volume']*(market[key] - portfolio[key]['strike'])))
```

What should I fix in order to have the total?
Thank you

Comment: So you want to add all of them together?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by "pnl of the portfolio"?

Comment: in the for loop u iterate every key and print it.  so of course it will show u 4 answers.
u just need inside the loop to add a sum variable.

example:
sum = 0

for key in market:
     value = (key, (portfolio[key]['volume']*(market[key] - portfolio[key]['strike'])))
     sum = float(sum) + value[1]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the total summary of your portfolio, then it should work like this

```py
summary = 0
for key in market:
    priceKey = portfolio[key]['volume']*(market[key] - portfolio[key]['strike'])
    print(key, (priceKey))
    summary = summary + priceKey

print(summary)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dict comprehension will give you the individual profit and losses.

Then you take the sum of the values of that dictionary:

```
In [15]: pnl = {k: (market[k] - portfolio[k]['strike'])*portfolio[k]['volume'] for k in portfolio}
Out[15]: 
{'AAPL': 447.2,
 'GOOG': 810.7400000000002,
 'TSLA': -893.5199999999998,
 'FB': -538.92}

In [16]: sum(pnl.values())
Out[16]: -174.49999999999943
```